# Hover state and transition in Chrome - multiple animations on one element do not apply

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, hover, css-transitions

When I apply transition in Chrome(24.0.1312.57) on hover it does not update background-color on mouse out. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WKVJ9/
Here is the code:

```
.transition{
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    background-color:cyan;
    position:relative;

}
.hoverme{
    border-radius:90px;
    display: block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50px;
    right:-90px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);

}
.wrapper:hover .hoverme{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    right:0;
}
.hoverme:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hoverme transition">
       Hover me
    </div>
</div>
```

If you hover .wrapper and .hoverme and then quickly move mouse away from this box the .hoverme element will only animate rotation and position.

On the site I am working on it does not even refresh hover state so when the animation is finished and the background stays with :hover background-color... Which for some reason I cannot reproduce here

Is it possible to make the background animate?

Comment: to make sure I get what you're asking ... you want the red circle to show as soon as mouse is hover?

Comment: No, when you hover the .wrapper and then .hoverme it works fine, but then if you move mouse from the .wrapper, .hoverme aniimates only position and rotation but stays in full red until the end of animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of position:absolute in .hoverme

try changing it to position:relative add margin-left:150px; (or required) to correct position of .hoverme ... like this:

```
.hoverme{
    border-radius:90px;
    display: block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:50px;
    right:-90px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:150px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);

}
```

check it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/WKVJ9/1/

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I guess the browser is rendering the div as an absolute positioned div in each step of the animation, so, only when it stops it is able to procede with the following commands. If you're moving around elements you shouldn't absolute position them.

Comment: as I am thinking about it, its not the best solution.. as i have another elements which are then affected by relative position of this box.. why absolute elements shouldn't be animated? As it works in Firefox quite well.. There really is not any work-around?

Comment: what I suggested was a possible work-around ... it can be hard to find the best work-around as things create more dependencies over time. Other thing I can think of that you can do is to close each of these animations inside a wrapper div so they don't interfere with each other.